# Credential Error in Node App when connecting to DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

i created a file named **api.js** using typescript in order to scan a dynamodb table as follows:

**Api.js**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";

var sns = new AWS.SNS();
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName: "Client"
};

// Get all posts
router.get('/posts', (req, res) => {

    ddb.scan(params, onScan);

    function onScan(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            // print all the movies
            console.log("Scan succeeded.");
            console.log(data)
        }
    }
});
```

but before passing the information i tried to test it. When i do `node server.js` i get the following credetial error:

```
API running on localhost:3000
Unable to scan the table. Error JSON: {
  "message": "Missing credentials in config",
  "code": "CredentialsError",
  "time": "2017-01-31T21:02:59.435Z",
  "retryable": true,
  "originalError": {
    "message": "Could not load credentials from any providers",
    "code": "CredentialsError",
    "time": "2017-01-31T21:02:59.435Z",
    "retryable": true,
    "originalError": {
      "message": "Connection timed out after 1000ms",
      "code": "TimeoutError",
      "time": "2017-01-31T21:02:59.435Z",
      "retryable": true
    }
  }
}
```

How can i get the credentials for the config and what is the best setup for both *development/localhost* and *production* of the application in order to connect with the right credentials to the table i have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [aws-docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) for the different ways you can setup your credentials.

> Here are the ways you can supply your credentials in order of recommendation:
>
> Loaded from AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles for Amazon EC2 (if running on Amazon EC2)
>
> Loaded from the shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials)
>
> Loaded from environment variables
>
> Loaded from a JSON file on disk
>
> *Caution*
>
> While it is possible to do so, we do not recommend hard-coding your AWS credentials in your application. Hard-coding credentials poses a risk of exposing your access key ID and secret access key.

We typically use the shared credentials file(~/.aws/credentials) for local development and then an IAM role for EC2 instances(stage/production)

The aws-sdk will check for environment variables(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) and the credentials file.